# How can I create a link in Excel or Google Sheets to a stock value in Morningstar?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, stock

I'd like to link the NAV value here
http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/c-header?t=QCSTIX
to a cell in Excel or Google Sheets. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/c-header?t=QCSTIX","//*"),9,2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is why Sheets has gotten on par with or better than Excel. Nice answer.